# TensorFlow Lite: Error converting to .tflite using toco

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to covert my TensorFlow frozen model to a tflite model. When I run toco, I get an error message reads as below

```
F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:982] Check failed: input_dims.size() == 4 (2 vs. 4)
```

Here is how I call toco:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--input_file=/tmp/output_graph.pb \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/tmp/my_model.lite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--inference_input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=input_layer \
--output_arrays=classes_tensor\
--input_shapes=1,227,227,3
```

Here is my terminal print out during the operation:

```
INFO: Analysed 0 targets (4 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 0 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.267s, Critical Path: 0.03s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
2018-01-05 10:24:23.011483: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_cmdline_flags.cc:178] --input_type is deprecated. It was an ambiguous flag that set both --input_data_types and --inference_input_type. If you are trying to complement the input file with information about the type of input arrays, use --input_data_type. If you are trying to control the quantization/dequantization of real-numbers input arrays in the output file, use --inference_input_type.
2018-01-05 10:24:25.853112: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1122] Converting unsupported operation: IsVariableInitialized
2018-01-05 10:24:25.853197: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1122] Converting unsupported operation: RefSwitch
2018-01-05 10:24:25.853241: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1122] Converting unsupported operation: RandomShuffleQueueV2
2018-01-05 10:24:25.853268: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1122] Converting unsupported operation: QueueDequeueUpToV2
2018-01-05 10:24:26.207160: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 64 operators, 90 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-01-05 10:24:27.327055: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After general graph transformations pass 1: 15 operators, 33 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-01-05 10:24:27.327262: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After general graph transformations pass 2: 15 operators, 34 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-01-05 10:24:27.327356: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:982] Check failed: input_dims.size() == 4 (2 vs. 4)
/home/olu/Dev/scratch_train_sign/freeze_graph_tf.sh: line 28:  8881 Aborted
```

I went into the propagate_fixed_sizes.cc file, and around line line 982 I found this comment below

```
// The current ArgMax implementation only supports 4-dimensional inputs with
// the last dimension as the axis to perform ArgMax for.
```

The only place in my training code where I used ArgMax is as below:

```
 predictions = { "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1, name="classes_tensor"), "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor") }
```

Do you know what the solution to this is? A solution to this will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After raising this as an issue on the TensorFlow bug tracker on GitHub, the answer boiled down to the fact that TLite for now doesn't completely support ArgMax. [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15948)